Why is Linux not using RAM but only Swap?
How can such an output of free -m be explained?
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           32036        1012         225           3        8400       31024
Swap:          32767       24138        8629

I understand having free memory to be low is no sign of alarm as Linux uses unused memory for buffers and file system caches (buff/cache). What's important to have enough available memory.
But why is the kernel not swapping in again? Nearly all memory is available.
I took this output from a continuously log-to-disk I setup as "every minute" cronjob. At that point in time the system was so unresponsive I could not even locally login anymore. After slowly typing username and password, there was a timeout (Login timed out after 60 seconds.), so I could not reach a shell and had to power-cycle the server to recover.
The journal is full of take too long, timeout and broken pipe messages as everything on the system is crawling and therefore malfunctioning.
I played around with vm.swappiness, having the default value of 60 reduced to 10 (to put the kernel more onto "only swap if it's really necessary"), but I have similar results.
I was hesitant to try a swapoff && swapon to bring the available memory back into play. Does the oom-killer take over if not everything fits into RAM? Or does the system crash then?

A little more background information about the concrete case:
I have a Proxmox setup, evaluating how stable everything runs. I really stress the machine having allocated more RAM to the VMs in total than I have. To my unterstanding, this should still work with paying a little price of using swap space, slowing things down.
I noticed that everything works stabile as I expected. I play around suspending VMs to disk, then starting other VMs. Swap gets used if needed and when VMs are suspended, Swap is being freed again.
But lately I added backup into my evaluation and this really crashes the machine. Over night, when PVE Backup is started RAM gets more and more available by consuming Swap. Backup speed falls from "1% per few seconds" to "1% per several hours" and eventually no progress at all. The machine gets unresponsive with that memory picture. The VMs are still running, but also their applications are malfunctioning as their system gets errors like interrupt took 2.2s, Watchdog timeout (limit 3min)!, CPU stuck for 23s!. In the morning I find myself an unresponsive host.

cat /proc/meminfo would give a lot more detail than free and might give a clue how the "available" memory is actually being used.

The kernel doesn't idly "swap something (a page or group of pages) in". It waits until a process references (reads, writes, executes, or does I/O) it. If the process memory represented by swapped out pages is freed, the swap space is likewise released.

Linux box with 100% used swap and 60% available RAM - is it normal? and more generally this search

To my question

But why is the kernel not swapping in again?

waltinator gave the answer clear and concise in the comments:

The kernel doesn't idly "swap something (a page or group of pages) in".


It turned out that my described problems (timeouts and the system not reacting anymore) were not related to memory shortage, but an unrelated issue with CIFS.
I was set on the wrong track by the CIFS issue, I suspected memory and therefore swapping to be the cause. Once CIFS was replaced with NFS, the system stayed responsive again.

Swapping in results in massive amounts of IO activity which could negatively affect system performance. If the swapped out applications are dormant, it makes little to no sense to swap them back in.
The free snapshot that you're showing doesn't contain historical data, thus we may never know what you were running before. It's possible that you had very heavy applications running, thus the kernel have swapped out so much.

Does the oom-killer take over if not everything fits into RAM? Or does the system crash then?

It takes into account the amount of virtual RAM available (RAM + swap), thus, no, it won't kill applications until your RAM and swap are both completely consumed.
Generally if you have enough RAM to accommodate all the running applications and still have enough free RAM, you could simply disable swap altogether. In my experience swap has more and more serious negatives than positives and it's only suitable for systems where there's not enough RAM to run applications at all.

Fully agree with your answer, but the last paragraph is wrong, isn't it? Without swap, whatever caused swapping in the first place would have run out of memory, and something would have had to die.

(swap is generally very useful, not sure where you see the negatives. It's not like it's going to be used if it's not necessary. I'd compare it to antibiotics: sure, terrible side effects, but a patient wouldn't be taking antibiotics if they didn't have a very problematic bacterial infection)

SWAP negatives: 1) unpredictable major latency spikes 2) unpredictable applications and system slow downs 3) unpredictable system behavior 4) storage wear and tear 5) possible information leak/security concerns. SWAP positive 1) Allowing to run more applications than there's physical RAM. That's all. In my company we have over 200 servers where zero have SWAP enabled. We've observed a critical performance loss and major throughput issues on servers with SWAP enabled. Personally I've not had SWAP enabled on any of my systems since 2004 with zero issues so far.


much better than unpredictable timing of inability to allocate memory 2) much better than unpredictable application crashes and OOM killings 3) you're confusing things, running out of memory leads to unpredictable behaviour, so here swap helps 4) agreeing with you on that, on old or low-quality storage media like SD cards, that's a problem. not a problem on HDDs or SSDs of the last 1.5 decades


But I do think you have a point. Something in your company's distributed system prefers running out of memory over having unpredictable latency (that might be standard things like file servers, or it might be custom things like say your company's own applications): that can be a valid design choice, but the way you portrait it, it would sound like there's something problematic in a large distributed system about it. I'd assume, knowing how well you usually know your stuff, that some problems are hard, and maybe sometimes crashing fast being better than becoming slow is the right choice.

If you're consistently running out of RAM, SWAP is extremely unlikely to help you but it could certainly make things a LOT worse. And, you're correct, I prefer a process to be killed by OOM or systemd-oomd, than wait for minutes and sometimes hours or even forever to system to swap out/swap in something because something is pushing RAM allocations and the kernel doesn't know this process is not important. I've seen way too many situations where systems became 100% unresponsive due to swapping out.

And you're dead wrong about SSDs. They have a very limited write resource and using SWAP is oftentimes the fastest way to kill them. HDDs are not affected except their write/reads speeds are so bad, using SWAP can basically stall the system indefinitely. Again I don't remember a single case in the last 20 years of using PCs and high load servers that SWAP has ever helped improve or fix things. But oh boy I've dealt with tons of semi-dead systems being hobbled by SWAP activity you have no control over.

Nah, when we're talking about SSDs these days, you see, for anything that is not "obviously" bad (as in: surprisingly cheap, but as soon as you check the specs, so slow that it must be very old technology) typically write endurances in the hundreds to thousands of TBW; even continously saturating their maximum write speeds, you'd need to be exercising the SSD for months with no break. I agree, if you design your systems so badly that that happens without you noticing, you deserve that swapping breaks your hardware!

I guess the takeaway here is that you need to have insight into what happens. If all you do is hope things get done in the maximum time you can allow them to happen before effects cascade to a breakdown, but you don't have any early warning signs, then yes, quickly failing totally at least lets you restart things. But it's still, simply, worse in every way than making the system more robust by adding swap, but having the means of knowing when infrastructure is about or has started to swap.

"until your RAM and swap are both completely consumed" - almost right - and an easier way to understand what's going on, but actually OOM Killer is triggered when there is insufficient free RAM to satisfy a request that cannot be declined, typically as a result of a COW page being written to (conversely, e.g. mmap and malloc operations simply fail without triggering OOMKiller).
